# SQL Server Select Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How would I copy a bunch of rows into a table and then change the values in one column and insert them back into the same table?

The table has these columns:

```
[PositionControlPositionId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionJobId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionRefLocationId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionCount]
  ,[PositionControlPositionEmploymentType]
  ,[PositionControlPositionLabel]
```

`PositionControlPositionID` is the primary Key
`PositionControlPositionRefLocationId` and `PositionControlPositionCount` are foreign keys

I have tried the below query but it didn't work

```
Insert into [dbo].[PositionControlPosition] ([PositionControlPositionId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionJobId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionRefLocationId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionCount]
  ,[PositionControlPositionEmploymentType]
  ,[PositionControlPositionLabel]) Select [PositionControlPositionId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionJobId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionRefLocationId]
  ,[PositionControlPositionCount]
  ,[PositionControlPositionEmploymentType]
  ,[PositionControlPositionLabel] from [dbo].[PositionControlPosition]
```

I have also searched google but couldn't find anything like I needed,

I realize this might be a trivial question so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they're all in the same table, wouldn't you just do an UPDATE ?

Comment: What went wrong? Did you violate a constraint?

Comment: @Jack - I have to keep the original records as they were, so i cant just update them.

Comment: If you are copying them to another table, why are you inserting them *again* into the original table?  Don't you want to save the existing records and then update the value in place?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am not copying them to another table i need to reinsert them with the new value into the existing table

Comment: @DinoRondelly, duplicating them?

Comment: Is `PositionControlPositionId` an identity column?

Comment: "[...]but it didn't work" Please explain how your query didn't work as expected or provide the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for takes the form.

```
 insert [table]
 select
           [a]
         , [b]
         , 'newCValue'
         , [d]
     from
         [table]
```

If you are not selecting all the columns then you should specify a column list on the insert

```
 insert [table]
         ( [a]
          ,[b]
          ,[c]
          ,[d])
 select
           [a]
         , [b]
         , 'newCValue'
         , [d]
     from
         [table]
```

In your case i suspect you are violating your primary key and I'm assuming its an identity column so this should work.

```
INSERT [dbo].[PositionControlPosition]
        (
          [PositionControlPositionJobId]
         ,[PositionControlPositionRefLocationId]
         ,[PositionControlPositionCount]
         ,[PositionControlPositionEmploymentType]
         ,[PositionControlPositionLabel]
        ) 
SELECT
          [PositionControlPositionJobId]
         ,[PositionControlPositionRefLocationId]
         ,[PositionControlPositionCount]
         ,[PositionControlPositionEmploymentType]
         ,[PositionControlPositionLabel]
    FROM
         [dbo].[PositionControlPosition]
```

This will duplicate the rows in `PositionControlPosition` excluding the primary key. If `PositionControlPositionId` is an identity column, it will be populated with new primary key values.